# Gradle include project on different parent

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Example structure:

```
messages/
  settings.gradle
  build.gradle
  consumer/
    build.gradle
  producer/
    build.gradle
  library/
     build.gradle

test/
  settings.gradle
  build.gradle
  library/
     build.gradle
```

The library folders are the same on different projects. However I develop/test the library on a real  "messages" projects and then distribute only library in open source.

I want to keep the two projects separate but "link" the library. I tried with a Mac folder alias (naive) which didn't work. Copy pasting the folder is not a great solution. Anyway to link those two?

e.g. have in messages/settings.gradle a path to the other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could "relocate" the project in your settings.gradle.

```
def libraryProject = findProject(':library')
libraryProject.projectDir = file('/path/to/other/project')
```

Comment: Nice one Mark! I edited your answer since projector needs a File object. And since now library is empty I added: `idea.module{ excluders += file('library')}`

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct. Gradle does not coerce the type in this case. Thanks!